# How to detect swipe direction?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, swipe

I would like to detect when a user makes a swipe gesture, and detect it's direction (left, right, up or down). I need to detect it not when the gesture is finished, but just when the iPhone knows the direction, even if it's not finished.

I am using XCode 5, and designing for iPhone 5 with iOS 7.

I would like to know the code that I have to paste to the .h, and to the .m, and if I have to drag and drop any item to the mainView.

Comment: I believe you can use a swipe gesture recogniser to do this. I'll get back to you. Just trying it out.

Comment: I recommend to take a look on the `state` prorpery of `UIGestureRecognizer` class.

Comment: @holex that's what I'm thinking too. Just putting a project together to test it.

Comment: @holex ah... from the docs `a swipe is a discrete gesture` it either happens or it doesn't. There is no intermediate state. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to know the direction when the gesture is not finished you would probably need the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and detect the direction using the `velocityInView:` method.

in the *.h file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPanGestureRecognizer *recognizer;

@end
```

in the *.m file:

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.recognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGesture:)];

    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.recognizer];
}

-(void)panGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Velocity: %@", NSStringFromCGPoint([sender velocityInView:self.view]));

    // Here You need to determine the direction
}
@end
```

Comment: This worked spectacularly!! One question I have, I am guessing this: `[sender velocityInView:self.view]` returns an object with the speed on x, and the speed on y, and then this function `NSStringFromCGPoint` will convert that object into a string. How can I get the X and Y as numeric values, so that I can determine the direction of the swipe? Thank you!

Comment: Returned value from `velocityInView:` is struct `CGPoint` not class. To get x and y values You simply call: `CGPoint point = [sender velocityInView:self.view]; CGFloat x = point.x; CGFloat y = point.y;`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily get using UISwipeGestureRecognizers property directions...
After :----

```
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRight)];
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.yourView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeft)];
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.gifWebView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];

-(void)swipeRight{
//Do whatever you want
}
-(void)swipeLeft{
//Do whatever you want
}
```

And For Before Swipe you can use UIPanGestureRecognizer

I hope it help you

Comment: TO asks : "I need to detect it not when the gesture is finished, but just when the iphone knows the direction, even if it's not finished". This answer answers another question.

Answer (score 0):

From [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizer_basics/GestureRecognizer_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH2-SW2):

> Gestures are either discrete or continuous. A discrete gesture, such
>   as a tap, occurs once. A continuous gesture, such as pinching, takes
>   place over a period of time. For discrete gestures, a gesture
>   recognizer sends its target a single action message. A gesture
>   recognizer for continuous gestures keeps sending action messages to
>   its target until the multitouch sequence ends,

So if you need to "detect it not when the gesture is finished, but just when the iphone knows the direction, even if it's not finished" you could not use UISwipeGestureRecognizer since it is a discrete one. You should use UIPanGestureRecognizer and analyse it is results to check is there a swipe gesture or not.

Answer (score 0):

To have a good example how it works, you can download a sample code provided by Apple:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleGestureRecognizers/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009460

Hope that helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

Swipe gestures are very quick. Swipe gesture recognizers are designed to fire once, not continuously. I don't think you will be able to get information about a swipe gesture that is "in flight" very easily.

If this is urgent, you will probably have to create a custom subclass of swipe gesture recognizer and add additional logic and delegate messages that would notify the delegate once the gesture recognizer decides that it has detected a swipe. That is way beyond your current skill level however.